# How can I commit Git hooks?

Tags: git

I'm trying to add a `pre-commit` script.

The script works, but Git ignores the changes to the file. It seems like Git ignores any changes I make in `.git`, but it isn't specified in `.gitignore`.

For example:

```
# Add a hook that runs Hello, World!
echo "#\!/bin/sh \n echo 'Hello, World!'" > .git/hooks/pre-commit

# Make the hook runnable
chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit

# Check changes
git status

# > Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
# > nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Therefore, how do I commit my hook to the repository?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+track+hooks

Answer (score 25):

I found it -

Create a directory in the project root, let's call it `git_hooks`. Add the script to it, and set the directory as the Git hooks target using `git config`.

```
# Create directory
mkdir git_hooks

# Add a hook that runs Hello, World!
echo "#\!/bin/sh \n echo 'Hello, World!'" > git_hooks/pre-commit

# Make the hook runnable
chmod +x git_hooks/pre-commit

# Configure git to use the new hook - it will stay with the repository
git config core.hooksPath "./git_hooks"

# The script will run on every commit:
git commit -am "added pre-commit hook"
> Hello, World!
```

Answer (score 3):

The `.git` repository isn't part of the repository. It *is* the repository.

If you want to save the configuration of your repository, I suggest you use another Git repository for that purpose.

Comment: So how do I add a hook? do I have to add another directory and force symlink it? what is the proper way to add a hook? this is what every tutorial shows me unless I use some fancy framework like python pre-commit, or js husky?